# Can sys.argv handle optional arguments?

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
script, lira_cbt, [eur_hedge] = argv

if eur_hedge == None:
    #Do x
else:
    #Do y
```

I want it to be able to run with just lira_cbt as an argument (doing x), or with both lira_cbt and eur_hedge (doing y). Can this be achieved with sys.argv?

Comment: If your CLI gets that complex, you should probably start using `argparse` (or `optparse` if you're stuck with some older version).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use the length of `sys.argv`

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
  # do X
else:
  # do Y
```

Comment: Can this be done if the length of `sys.argv` is only ever going to be 0 or 1?

Answer (score 8):

If this is to be part of more than a throw-away script, consider using argparse http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html

At the moment it will be much more complicated, but it will help you keep documented the options your program accepts and also provide useful error messages unlike a 
"too many values to unpack" that the user might not understand.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to extract the values from the argv list using `try`:

```
lira_cbt = sys.argv[1]
try:
  eur_hedge = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
  eur_hedge = None

if eur_hedge == None:
    # Do X
else:
    # Do Y
```

You could also take a look at [getopt](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html) for a more flexible parser of command line arguments.

Comment: optparse or argparse would be much better than getopt!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the length of `sys.argv`.

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    # Error, not enough arguments

lira_cbt = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # Do X
else:
    eur_hedge = sys.argv[2]
    # Do Y
```

Comment: But no way to specifically pull the value in eur_hedge without throwing up a need more/too many variable to unpack argument?

Comment: No, there is no way to do it, unless you want to convert it to a function call and use something like `def main(script, lira_cbt, eur_hedge=None)` and `main(*sys.argv)`, which I definitely wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest an alternative approach:

```
from sys import argv
option_handle_list = ['--script', '--lira_cbt', '--eur_hedge']
options = {}
for option_handle in option_handle_list:
    options[option_handle[2:]] = argv[argv.index(option_handle) + 1] if option_handle in argv else None
if options['eur_hedge'] == None:
    #Do x
else:
    #Do y
```

Comment: While this may work, using a module like `argparse` for this task would be both easier and more pythonic.

Comment: @YSelf I am not debating on the easier / more traditional solution. Just answering the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that tries to read the argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmzbm.jpg) input but does something else if one isn't provided.

```
from sys import argv

try:
    x = argv[1]
    print("x" + " Was given as an argument")
except:
    print("No Input Provided")
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmzbm.jpg)