# Remove or keep specific columns in csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a simple script to either remove last n columns from csv file or to keep first n columns only in csv file:

```
from sys import argv
import csv

if len(argv) == 4:
  script, inputFile, outputFile, n = argv
  n = [int(i) for i in n.split(",")]
else:
  script, inputFile, outputFile = argv
  n = 1

with open(inputFile,"r") as fin:
  with open(outputFile,"w") as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
      writer.writerow(row[:n])
```

Example usage (remove last two columns): `removeKeepColumns.py sample.txt out.txt -2`

How do I extend this to handle possibility to keep/remove specific set of columns, e.g.:

- remove columns 3,4,5
- keep only columns, 1,4,6

I can split input arguments separted by comma into array, but don't know hot to pass this to `writerow(row[])`

Links to scripts I used to create my example:

- [Delete or remove last column in CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245738/delete-or-remove-last-column-in-csv-file-using-python)
- [Can sys.argv handle optional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442313/can-sys-argv-handle-optional-arguments)
- [What is the easiest way to convert list with str into list with int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424412/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-list-with-str-into-list-with-int)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724856/picking-out-items-from-a-python-list-which-have-specific-indexes#724881

Comment: @Jasper I don't get it, would you mind to extend your comment a little?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get a (non-continuous) subsequence from a CSV. The linked question tells you exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment ([Picking out items from a python list which have specific indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724856/picking-out-items-from-a-python-list-which-have-specific-indexes#724881))

```
from sys import argv
import csv

if len(argv) == 4:
  script, inputFile, outputFile, cols_str = argv
  cols = [int(i) for i in cols_str.split(",")]

with open(inputFile,"r") as fin:
  with open(outputFile,"w") as fout:
    writer=csv.writer(fout)
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
      sublist = [row[x] for x in cols]
      writer.writerow(sublist)
```

This should (untested) keep all the columns that are given as comma-separated list in the 3rd parameter. To remove the given colums,

```
sublist = [row[x] for x not in cols]
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Well there was an accepted answer already, here's my solution:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="your_file.csv")
>>> sheet.column.select([1,4,5]) # the column indices to keep
>>> sheet.save_as("your_filtered_file.csv")
>>> exit()
```

Here is more details on [filtering](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial02.html)